# How to know which HttpClient headers to use?

Tags: c#, http-headers, httpclient, socketexception

I'm a bit at a loss as to how to approach this issue. The title says it all. When I try scraping the html from a site a get a SocketException. I've managed to figure out that it has something to do with headers but I have no idea which headers I'm supposed to use under various circumstances. I have the following:

```
    private async void parseHtml(string url)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
        var html = await client.GetStringAsync(url); //SocketException here

        //Parse html, etc.
    }
```

Comment: "*I've managed to figure out that it has something to do with headers*" -- How? What did you see, what did you do, and how did that change what you saw?

Comment: "*SocketException here*" -- What is the full exception message and stack trace?

Comment: The core headers you need will already be added by `HttpClient`. Anything else comes down to the requirements of an individual server. Sometimes the server will accept a limited range of `User-Agent` values, for example, presumably to make scraping a hair harder.

Comment: Compare a working app to server with your app using a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler.  Every server is different and without server documentation you are guessing.  HttpClient is not very intelligent and adds very few headers to a request.  I normally try an IE and see if it works.  Then use sniffer to get the working headers.

Comment: @canton7 
SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
There was nothing useful in the trace. I just noticed that individuals would set their own headers.

Comment: And you get this SocketException on a url that you can request yourself in a browser, successfully?

Comment: @John I did not know that. I was under the assumption that it wasn't sending any headers. I did add a header for a similar page which solved my issue but no luck for a different page.
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8");

Comment: @canton that is correct

Comment: Have you tried adding a User-Agent header, as @John said?

Comment: @jdweng that's very useful to know. Seems like I might just go for wireshark then, but then the question still remains as to how a browser will send the correct headers

Comment: @Max it's less "the browser sends the correct headers" and more "browsers send a standard set of headers, and websites might expect those headers"

Comment: But, "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time" means that you never managed to establish the connection. It doesn't matter what headers you're trying to send, because you never managed to send them, as you never managed to connect.

Comment: @canton7 the thing is that I was getting that same message prior to adding a header for the page that managed to load. I did try sending adding a user-agent header but that didn't work. I used https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-http-headers-is-my-browser-sending to get some headers but I'll try adding the rest and see if that does anything

Comment: A browser defaults to more headers than the Net Library does for HttpRequest.

Comment: So it appears that once I added the following 3 headers that it ended up working:
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Language", "en;q=0.9");
It's still a hassle to guess and check though